# Ubuntu weird process use 60-70 percent of the CPU

Tags: malware, cpu-load, vps

Recently I noticed that my VPS is doing a lot of work, I ran 'top' command and I saw a process with a weird name who using 60-70 percent of the CPU (I attached pictures).

When I kill those process the VPS seems to work fine.
What should I do in this situation?

How can I remove the process?

Thanks.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

`readlink -f /proc/{PID}/exe` will return the path of the process binary

`lsof -p {PID}` will return where to look for investigation

[ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/) antivirus can help too.

```
sudo apt install clamav
```

Bonne chance